# How to add title on GeoFence circle in google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-geofence

I am working on Geofence in the android google map.
I am able to add GeoFence in Map. 
I need to add a title of Geofence within the circle or bottom of the circle.
I don't want to add a title on Marker.

```
map.addCircle(CircleOptions()
      .center(reminder.latLng)
      .radius(radius)
      .strokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent))
      .fillColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorReminderFill)))
```

for Marker I can use this

```
map.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(reminder.name)
    .snippet("Radius: " + reminder.radius)).showInfoWindow()
```

[image]

The requirement is to add title inside or bottom of the circle not on marker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put them inside a circle in your map, you can try to make the text into an image. Then you either use this image as your [custom marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker#customize_the_marker_image). As you don't want it to be in a marker, you can use [ground overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/groundoverlay#add_an_overlay). Since you want to put it inside the circle, You can use the center coordinate as the position of your marker or ground overlay. You might also need to adjust the size of your image that will fit inside your circle.